# Hosting Power BI reports on AWS

Tags: powerbi

How to host power BI reports in Amazon web services?. After I prepare reports in power BI, how i can host the reports in AWS so that internal users can access the reports without login credentials. I am planning to publish the BI reports on AWS so that internal users can access it on cloud.

Comment: Please add some code here, so someone can suggest you what to do?

Comment: I don't think that is an option. Power BI requires a Pro license for any user who wants to access a shared report. Microsoft has its own cloud platform on which PowerBI is hosted. AWS is definitely not an option. In general, you should ask these questions in the [Power BI community](https://community.powerbi.com/), where you'll find a lot more Power BI experts than here.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @sarvan did you try SQL Server Reporting Services + Power BI hosted on a AWS VM?